# nullptr_type not supported by simple_type_specifier

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I wish to have a function `fn`, which takes sets of pointers to `const` and non-`const` objects. I am writing a template to do this.

```
template<typename T1,
         typename T2,
         std::enable_if<std::is_same<T1,NodeType *>::value && std::is_same<T2,EdgeType *>::value, std::nullptr_t>::type = nullptr>
static void fn(unordered_set<T1> &nodeSet, unordered_set<T2>& edgeSet);
```

In the above example, I want to be able to pass `unordered_set<const NodeType *>` as well as `unordered_set<NodeType *>`(simliar with `EdgeType`). However, I get an error:
`‘nullptr_type’ not supported by simple_type_specifier`. Could someone help?

Comment: replace `,std::nullptr_t>::type = nullptr` with `, int>::type = 0`

Comment: I did think of that. But could you tell me why ``nullptr`` doesn't work?

Comment: The error isn't helpful at all, but you're just missing a `typename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except from some `typename`s you're missing, to achieve this you should use `std::remove_const` and `std::remove_pointer` type traits as:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2,
  typename std::enable_if<
   std::is_same<typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_pointer<T1>::type>::type, NodeType>::value &&
   std::is_same<typename std::remove_const<typename std::remove_pointer<T2>::type>::type, EdgeType>::value,
   typename std::nullptr_t>::type = nullptr>
static void fn(std::unordered_set<T1> &nodeSet, std::unordered_set<T2>& edgeSet);
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7799581fc67bca04)

Comment: I ended up keeping it as just T1 and T2, and adding a static assert. Is one approach better/worse than the other?

Comment: Also, I read somewhere that cv-qualifiers on template parameters are ignored. I obviously misunderstood. Could you tell me what that was supposed to mean?

Comment: On the first question, everything is determined during compile time, thus either of the solutions sounds equivalent to me, On the second question : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction